# How to turn off views asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Googled this and similar questions, I've asked questions in Lab discussion, I've searched for the answer here, but for some reason, getting this evades me.

We have a frmMain.aspx that contains links and image buttons for various pages and functions on the site. Sample of that code is below:

```
<a href="frmSalaryCalculator.aspx" id="linkbtnCalculator">Annual Salary Calculator&nbsp;
        <img alt="Annual Salary Calculator" src="images/calculator.jpg" 
            style="width: 57px; height: 54px" id="imgbtnCalculator" 
            name="imgbtnCalculator" /><br /></a>
```

The instructions are "Modify the main form so that the following options are turned off for nonadmin users: "

I'm quite certain I need to use if/else statements, but because I am still learning the syntax, I'm not quite sure how to make this happen.  The code for the frmMain.aspx.cs is below.  All help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class frmMain : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is my second comment
        clsDataLayer.SaveUserActivity(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"), "frmPersonnel");
    }

    private void SetSecurityOptions()
    {

    }
    protected void u_ViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The markup shows an HTML link with no runat="Server" tag.  That means the server code you are displaying cannot touch the element at all.  If you want to modify controls at the server, they need to be Server Controls.  Try dropping a LinkButton onto your form.

Comment: I have that in the <head> tag, does it need to be elsewhere?

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

Comment: It has to be on every control you are going to access with C# code. Try dropping a LinkButton onto your form.  When you type the id in the C# code, intellisense will pop up a list of properties

Answer (score 1):

```
// check if session security level is A
if (Session["SecurityLevel"] == "A")
{
    btnSubmit.Visible = true;
    //else, set submit button to not visible
}
else {
    btnSubmit.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`linkbtnCalculator.IsEnabled =` //code to check if the current user has roles, bool

Comment: Thank you for the response.  While I understand I need to check if the current user has roles, that is part of the problem I am having, I don't know exactly how to do that nor the syntax to use

Answer (score 0):

you can do this purely in the aspx using the Loginview control.  Not as flexible as code behind logic but its a quick effective way to get the result.

Loginview keys you display different content based on your authentication (loggen in vs anonymous) or even based on roles.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx for a nice article on how to use the control worth role templates